# create table with clob column fails

Tags: oracle

What is the Problem with

```
 CREATE TABLE sessions (session_data CLOB(4000),SESSION_ID VARCHAR2(40));
```

I always get a `Query failed #907 ORA-00907: Rechte Klammer fehlt`

Comment: fwiw, that translates to "Right bracket missing"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't specify clob size

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (session_data CLOB,SESSION_ID VARCHAR2(40));
```